# jQuery event fires multiple times

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I have a problem with jQuery events.

First let me explain the setup of the page:

The main-page.php is consisted of:

a) a header (where the logo is)

b) a navbar (where the various selections are)

c) a dynamic content area (Where the content of the clicked element on the navbar will be loaded)

d) Footer

Lets say that the navbar is consisted of | HOME | MESSAGES | ABOUT US | ...

The content of HOME is a separate PHP file, with a separate CSS and JS file. The same goes for all selections.

As soon as I select HOME (for example), i remove any content from the DYNAMIC CONTENT area and I place the content of HOME using AJAX. At the same time I remove any CSS/JS files associated with the previous content and I link the CSS/JS files associated with the one loaded. This part is working perfectly.

Now, if I switch from one selection to other selections (lets say from HOME --> MESSAGES --> ABOUT US and then back to HOME), if I click on a button inside HOME it will fire the event multiple times. This is even worse if that event is causing an AJAX call to the server (imagine calling the server 5 times instead of 1).

**The reason I use the `on()` event on the element with radio-element class is because is a future DOM element. Initially this element is not on the page.

A sample of JS code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.radio-element', function(){

    $.ajax({
        
            url: "js/ajax/ajaxcall.php",
            success: function(output){

                $('#ajaxcall-container').html(output);
    
            }               
    });
        
});
```

What I do is, as soon as I click an element with the class of radio-element, I go in the server and i fetch the output of `ajaxcall.php` script.

Watching the NETWORK tab inside INSPECT ELEMENT, I see that the click event is executing the AJAX call multiple times. Sometimes 2, other 3 or even 5.

What I did to solve the problem (non of them is working 100%):

A) unbind the event before binding it using "**off**"

```
$(document).off('click','.radio-element').on('click', '.radio-element', function(){ .... });
```

B) Use event.**stopImmediatePropagation()**

```
$(document).on('click', '.radio-element', function(event){ 

     event.stopImmediatePropagation();

     //rest of code

 });
```

Below is a solution that I haven't tried yet since I read in an article that it will not stop event binding process, it will just prevent multiple event execution (don't know if this will cause other problems).

```
$(document).on('click', '.radio-element', function(event){ 

     if(event.handled !== true) 
    {
        //Code goes here
        event.handled = true;
    }

 });
```

The problem with multiple event firing is that there are AJAX calls that perform actions that are not supposed to be executed more than once (eg. send email to clients).

Also, this behavior (multiple event firing) is not something i can predict. Sometimes it works fine, some others it fires the event 5 times in a row.

I have been searching the web for a week now, but everything i tried did not solve the problem. Any solution will be much appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `.one('click')` instead of `.on('click')` ?

Comment: is this an SPA? Sounds like you might have some cached javascript. Try hard refreshing the page and click and see how many times the item is called. Basically I'm wondering if the file that is binding this click function is being brought on the page more than once.

Comment: No i haven't tried one() because i want to be able to select it again and perform the same action. For example if this event is binded on a radio button selection..

Comment: use one()... and at the end of the function bind it again using one()

Comment: Can you just load all of the js and CSS at one time, instead of per 'view' ? Just because you are using AJAX, to switch out content, doesn't mean you  need to send http requests for different functions and styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based upon what I am reading here - I would guess you are bringing on the js file with the click bind event more than once. If you are using custom routing or single page app and not refreshing the page, it is very likely based on what you are saying.

You could test this theory by adding a console.log inside the click event (above the ajax) and fool around with it and check the logs. If you are clicking it and it is logging whatever you logged more than once, then you know that this is the issue. I don't think it is the ajax.

Comment: Once i press a selection on the navbar i remove all JS files and i link only the JS file of the selection clicked. I do the same with CSS. But i will test this in a while.

Comment: @christostsang I've run into this exactly problem and my guess is you are loading the js file more than once. For example if you are using php to swap pages and you have the js file in that one php page, if you go to another page and come back - you will have loaded that js file in the browser twice (this is assuming you have no refreshed the page or are not using something like requirejs), hence the event firing more than once.

Comment: Currently i am not at home to test it, but just to give you an idea this is how o remove js files: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml  . Also i use the same way to add the js file i want. At any time in my HTML i see only one instance of the home js file. Is this accurate? Or does it load the multiple times the same file and i just cant see it?

Comment: @christostsang just test it  when you can :). That will be the fastest and most determinate  way of seeing if you have multiple copies. Keep in mind when you bring a js file in the browser keeps it up within itself, so again, if you arent refreshing the page for example and bringing on that page that is pulling the js file twice, the browser is now holding onto 2 copies and will have the event bound twice.

Comment: Indeed the problem is NOT within AJAX. The dynamic content is only consisted of PHP/HTML; no JS/CSS files are coming with it. The way i link the CSS/JS of the clicked option is again by the method mentioned before,AFTER removing all previously CSS/JS of other views. What is permanent is the JS/CSS files of the shell page (the one that is hosting the dynamic content). If i link all CSS/JS files of all options(HOME/MESSAGES/ABOUT) inside the shell page, how is going to react when the dynamic content comes in? Will it work? Does the AJAX call force the script to be read again from top to bottom?

Comment: @christostsang Well you have a bunch of options,  you first might want to figuire out in your method exactly where/when the js files are being loaded. There are lots of solutions to problems like this you can use anything from a javascript framework to something like requireJS. You could just have all your javascript upfront and use document.on like youre using - not recommending this though.

Comment: @christostsang Think of it like this - you have one page, every time you load a js file onto the page (however you bring it in, it doens't really matter), it sits in the browser. **If you don't refresh the page or have something that destroys the reference to the js when you switch the view/page, when you bring that view back on a second copy will be pushed up into the browser**. THIS is your problem, and this is a great reason to use said technologies above. It has nothing to do with the ajax itself, it's just the method in which you are doing this that is the problem.

Comment: @christostsang Just to follow up with one last thing - if you are using that method and it *should* be removing the js - my guess is it actually is not. Again, I might consider tesing with a log/alert. You could even put it at the very top of the entire js you are loading then you would know for sure and could determine exactly when it is loading the new one on.

Comment: the double firing was caused initially due to a LABEL around an input field. These 2 elements were surrounded by a div and i was targeting that div. Thus the click event was triggered twice. But for sure if you include the same js file twice you will have problems of that nature.

Answer (score 1):

I have also encountered the same problem quite a while. I solved this by unbinding all the events associated with the element before executing new event handlers. 
Use like this:

```
$('#element').unbind().click()
  {
    //write something here
  }
```

This will unbind previous event handlers before creating a new one. I think this will works well for you.

If you are using jquery version 1.7+
you can use off() like this

```
$('#element').Off().click()
  {
    //write something here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess based on your description is that you are not removing the event listeners. So every time you switch tab/page the same event will be added over and over again. Even though you have tried to do it, something is not going right. I doubt it has anything to do with Ajax.

Comment: Do you mean to remove all event listeners upon navbar selection?

Comment: @christostsang this is exactly what is being suggested above in ajmajmajma 's answer